# count of the fraction of each category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to this

```
ID  category  fraction_0  fraction 1
A    1         1/3         2/3
A    1         1/3         2/3
A    0         1/3         2/3 
C    1         0/1         1/1
B    0         1/1         0/1
```

fraction_0 and fraction_1 are output.
fraction_0 is group by ID, in ID A, how many in category is 0. For take A as an example, in 3 As, there is one zero and two 1s. So fraction_0 is 1/3, and fraction_1 is 2/3.

my code looks as below

```
df.groupby('ID')['category'].agg(lamda x: x/x.sum())
```

However, this piece of code does not help me categorize 0 and 1. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `value_counts` with `normalize=True` to get the fractions. Then we need to reshape and `merge` the result back to the original.

```
res = (df.groupby('ID')['category']      # For category within each ID
        .value_counts(normalize=True)    # Calculate %
        .unstack(-1)                     # Each category to a column
        .fillna(0)                       # No occurrences -> 0%
        .add_prefix('fraction_'))        # Modify column names

df = df.merge(res, on='ID', how='left')
```

---

```
  ID  category  fraction_0  fraction_1
0  A         1    0.333333    0.666667
1  A         1    0.333333    0.666667
2  A         0    0.333333    0.666667
3  C         1    0.000000    1.000000
4  B         0    1.000000    0.000000
```

Comment: what does unstacked(-1) means here

Comment: @totolow after the groupby you get a MultiIndexed Series, where the 0th level is the ID and the first level is the category. I.e. look at the output of `df.groupby('ID')['category'].value_counts(normalize=True)`. Then unstack turns the categories into their own columns.